# Proper way to include headers in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I just found out i've been doing this wrong for the whole time. I haven't used any ide and only use gcc. I have started using makefile also to compile my large project.

most of the time the file structure was this

```
├── makefile
└── src
    ├── folder1
    │   ├── header1.cpp
    │   └── header1.h
    ├── folder2
    │   ├── header2.cpp
    │   └── header2.h
    └── main.cpp
```

on `header2.cpp`, when I include `header1.h` I do it like this

file *header2.cpp*

```
#include "../folder1/header1.h"
```

this is how I include the other files from another folder.
I think I am doing wrong. most of the tutorial I have watch uses Ide and they don't include it like that.

some include it like  this

```
#include "folder1/header1.h"
```

or others put it in a one folder like `headers/`

then include it like this.

```
#include "header1.h"
```

Can anyone guide me. how do i achieve this. I been doing this bad including I guess.

I don't want to include files like this

```
 #include "../../../../sofarfolder1/header1.h"
```

thanks. it makes me puke everytime I see my code.

Comment: Makefiles typically have `CFLAGS` options to add to the the include path with the `-I` compiler option. In your case it might be `-Isrc`. Then you can do `#include <folderX/headerX.h>`. Or if you put it in the `headers` directory it would be `-Iheader` and then you can do `#include <headerX.h>`

Comment: @AlanAu More like CPPFLAGS, since the pre-processor is the one that does all the including.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `-Idir` flag to tell GCC to look for header files in the directory `dir`, if you don't want to use `../`.

More info: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Answer (score 5):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html

In your makefile, you can invoke gcc with `-I../../../sofardirectory`

That way, it will look in that directory for headers you include.

Answer (score 1):

How I deal with headers depends in if they are going to be installed (as with a library) or not.

Private headers I would keep in the project source folder:

```
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── header1.cpp
    └── header1.h
    ├── header2.cpp
    └── header2.h
    └── main.cpp
```

Then just include them like this:

```
#include "header1.h"
```

Public headers (to be installed) I generally put in a project subfolder like this:

```
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── project
    │   ├── header1.h
    │   └── header2.h
    └── header1.cpp
    └── header2.cpp
    └── main.cpp
```

And I include them like:

```
#include <project/header1.h>
```

In order to locate the public headers you need to set a compiler flag. For `GCC` that is `-I`

```
g++ -Isrc ... etc ...
```

When the headers are installed they will go somewhere like `/usr/include`:

```
 ── usr
    └── include
        ├── project
        │   ├── header1.h
        │   └── header2.h
```

And client software will include them the same way:

```
#include <project/header1.h>
```

But they will supply different flag settings to find them:

```
g++ -I/usr/include ... etc ...
```

Comment: You shouldn't include headers from the same project with `<>`. `""` are meant for that.

Comment: @tuple_cat For internal project headers I do use `""`. It is only for public headers that are to be installed for others to use that I use the `<>` notation. I feel it is useful to use the same `API` that  you expect others to use when including your headers. Also I think it serves to document, in the code, which headers are part of the public `API` and which are purely internal. However I am certainly open to reasons why it might be harmful?

Answer (score 1):

An unusual alternative to using compiler flags to specify additional include directories is to use the C Preprocessor to create defined constants for the include file path.

For instance if you have an include file with a relative path such as `#include "../../stuff/lib1/thing1.h"` you can do something like the following.

```
#define THING1_H_PATH  "../../stuff/lib1/thing1.h"
  // ...
#include THING1_H_PATH
```

The gcc C Preprocessor documentation, [The C Preprocessor in section 1.3.2, The #include Directive](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html) has this to say:

> #include anything else
>
> This variant is called a computed #include. Any `#include' directive
>   whose argument does not fit the above two forms
>   is a computed include. The text anything else is checked for macro
>   calls, which are expanded (see [section 1.4 Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC10)). When this is done,
>   the result must fit one of the above two variants--in particular, the
>   expanded text must in the end be surrounded by either quotes or angle
>   braces.
>
> This feature allows you to define a macro which controls the
>   file name to be used at a later point in the program. One application
>   of this is to allow a site-specific configuration file for your
>   program to specify the names of the system include files to be used.
>   This can help in porting the program to various operating systems in
>   which the necessary system header files are found in different places.